# Converting line of bytes to string

Tags: java, string, byte

I created a program that takes user input and converts it into a char array. It then turns each char in the array to it's corresponding byte value, and prints all of them in a single line.

I am now creating a second program that I want to be able to paste that line of bytes into it as user input, and then have it display the original message in ASCII (English)

Here is my code so far:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;


    public class MessageDecoder
    {
         public static void main(String[] args)
         {
              System.out.println("Please enter your encrypted message and press Enter: ");
              Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
              byte b = reader.nextByte();
         }
    }
```

I have tried concatenating the line of bytes into a String, like this

```
    System.out.println(b + "");
```

But that (probably obviously) didn't work.

What do I need to do?

Comment: ASCII is inadequate for English writing. Thankfully, the Java designers decided that String would be Unicode/UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
  System.out.println((char)b);
```

However from you comments as far as I can understand you have "encrypted your char" in numbers, hence an A has become 65 (2 bytes 6 and 5). The problem of "decrypting" this is that you have lost information es. AA = 6565 (and this could also be char 6 char 5 ecc). So what you need is a system to understand how it was grouped.

Solution A is to set fixed with (at least 3 chars since a byte max is 256) this means that the A becomes 065

Solution B use a seperatore (that is not present in file es. EOT  (char)5.

If solution A to decrpyt you read the input (also as string) then you loop 3 chars by 3 char, cast to Integer --> cast to char and you got your original char.

Solution B, maybe simpler you can use the split function on the input string

```
  String[] stringArray = input.split(char)5);
```

Then loop this and on every string

```
    int result = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]).
    char c = (char)result;
```

I did not give you all the code, but I hope it helps

Comment: lol are you being sarcastic about the encryption? lol I know it's not state-of-the-art, its just for some friends. but anyway, it throws this exception:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException: For input string: "104105321161041011141013210810597114"
 at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextByte(Unknown Source)
 at MessageDecoder.main(MessageDecoder.java:11)                                          By the way, thanks for the help!

Comment: byte b = reader.nextByte();, you need to input a byte....(try a Integer number between 0 and 256)

Comment: a byte as in 1 byte? like 98?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a line of bytes... such as 9732108105110101321111023298121116101115

Comment: I guess instead of inputing a byte (0-256) from System.in, you should read your file... search google java read file.... and then do the system out

Comment: When you "encrypted" for example an A char become 65, if you know try to insert in your program 65 you will see A

Comment: that's true. But it won't do, for example, two A's, such as 6565

Comment: well you are reading byte by byte so you need to input 65 and then 65.. (note 6565 is not a byte max 256). this is done by loops ex. for...or while (if System.in you do a loop that breaks on certain number), you need to input the number your self, if you do it reading from file you just loop the bytes in.read(), until you hit the end

Comment: If you have fun encrypting this could be a good start http://www.codejava.net/coding/file-encryption-and-decryption-simple-example

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your encrypted message and press Enter: ");
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String val = reader.nextLine();
char[] buffer = val.toCharArray();
byte[] b = new byte[buffer.length];
for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString((byte) buffer[i] & 255 | 256).substring(1)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would go about it

1. Read the bytes (keep them 2 digits, HEX to keep this simple, in other words, 9 is entered as 09) **as a String**
2. Start with an empty String(Buffer) as your decrypted String.
3. In a while loop, simply substring 2 characters at a time and use [Byte.valueOf with radix 16](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) as the convertor to byte and append that as char to your decrypted String.

Hope this helps!